# Probability of university students studying mathematics

Tags: probability, statistics

At MIT, forty percent of the students are in Mathematics.
Thirty percent of Mathematics students study Probabilistic Systems, and fifty percent of the students studying Probabilistic Systems are in Mathematics.  What percentage of students at MIT are either in Mathematics or studying Probabilistic Systems?

work:

assuming no. of students=100

m denotes student in mathematics, p denotes student in probabilistic systems

n(m) + n(p) - n(m and p)

=40+24-12

=52 = 52%

Comment: Your working is correct. Please use mathjax to format.

Answer (score 1):

$40$ students out of $100$ are in Maths. $0.3 \cdot 40 = 12$ of them are in PS too. And this $12$ seems to be a $50\%$ of PS students. Hence there are $24$ students in PS course. Hence, $$n(\{ \text{Math students}\} \cup \{ \text{PS students}\}) = 40 + 24 -12 = 52$$

So, the answer is $52\%$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a drawing of the solution. Your solution is correct but to check it, and to face more difficult examples, a Venn diagram like the following is very useful (IMHO)

[image]